# how to subset pandas dataframe with list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this.

```
     order_id   latitude  longitude 
0      519     19.119677  72.905081
1      520     19.138250  72.913190
2      521     19.138245  72.913183
3      523     19.117662  72.905484
4      524     19.137793  72.913088
5      525     19.119372  72.893768
6      526     19.116275  72.892951
7      527     19.133430  72.913268
8      528     19.136800  72.917185
9      529     19.118284  72.901114
10     530     19.127193  72.914269
11     531     19.114269  72.904039
12     532     19.136292  72.913941
13     533     19.119075  72.895115
14     534     19.119677  72.905081
15     535     19.119677  72.905081
```

And one list

```
DB
Out[658]: 
[['523'],
['526', '533'],
['527', '528', '532', '535'],
['530', '519'],
['529', '531', '525', '534'],
['520', '521', '524']]
```

Now I want to subset dataframe on list elements. There are 6 elements in a list and every element have a sublist of `order_id`. So, for every sub element I want corresponding latitude and longitude. And then I want to calculate haversine distance between each `order_id location`:

```
 DB[2]
 ['527', '528', '532', '535']
```

Then I want to subset on main dataframe for latitude and longitude pairs. So it should return me an array like this:

```
array([[ 19.11824057,  72.8939447 ],
   [ 19.1355074 ,  72.9147978 ],
   [ 19.11917348,  72.90518167],
   [ 19.127193  ,  72.914269  ]])
```

(Just an example not a correct lat long pairs).

I am doing following:

```
db_lat  = []
db_long = []
for i in range(len(DB)):
   l = len(DB[i])
   for j in range(l):
      db_lat.append(tsp_data_unique.latitude[tsp_data_unique['order_id'] ==   
      ''.join(DB[i][j])])  
      db_long.append(tsp_data_unique.longitude[tsp_data_unique['order_id'] 
      == ''.join(DB[i][j])])
```

But it gives me a list of all the lat and long present in DB. Here I am not able to distinguish which lat and long belong to which DB elements. So, for every DB elements (6 in my case) I want 6 arrays of lat and long. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would convert your `int` column to `str` to compare the dataframe with the values of the list:

```
df['order_id'] = df['order_id'].apply(str)
```

and then set the index on `order_id`:

```
df = df.set_index('order_id')
```

Then you can do something like:

```
pairs = df.loc[DB[2]].values
```

obtaining:

```
array([[ 19.13343 ,  72.913268],
       [ 19.1368  ,  72.917185],
       [ 19.136292,  72.913941],
       [ 19.119677,  72.905081]])
```

EDIT:
Iterating over your list you can then:

```
In [93]: for i in range(len(DB)):
   ....:     p = df.loc[DB[i]].values
   ....:     print p
   ....:     
[[ 19.117662  72.905484]]
[[ 19.116275  72.892951]
 [ 19.119075  72.895115]]
[[ 19.13343   72.913268]
 [ 19.1368    72.917185]
 [ 19.136292  72.913941]
 [ 19.119677  72.905081]]
[[ 19.127193  72.914269]
 [ 19.119677  72.905081]]
[[ 19.118284  72.901114]
 [ 19.114269  72.904039]
 [ 19.119372  72.893768]
 [ 19.119677  72.905081]]
[[ 19.13825   72.91319 ]
 [ 19.138245  72.913183]
 [ 19.137793  72.913088]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it. Similar to what @Fabio has posted.

```
new_DB=[]
for i in range(len(DB)):
    new_DB.append(tsp_data_unique[(tsp_data_unique['order_id']).isin(DB[i])]  
    [['latitude','longitude']].values)
```